# htaccess conditional redirect if domains matched

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect **non-https** to https if domains **matched** and also **non-www** to www for all domains.

here is my code which works except it doesn't redirect non-www to www on https versions only.

NOTE: I seperated rules for non-www and www versions because if i added www in the url it would ad www 2x.

```
RewriteEngine On

#all non-www to www (without HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

#non-https to https if these 2 domains matched - and since there is already www don't add it.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainA\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainB\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

#non-https to https if these 2 domains matched - and also www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainB\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.html
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @anubhava if i access https:domainA.com it will not add www to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this, it should add www. to any domains with https://

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

**The code was fine. The problem was that www was not configured in host.**